# How to make automation after successful payment capture using order information

Tags: event-observer, shipping, place-order

When a user makes an order on my Magento 2.4 website, I need to scrape all of the data of that order after the payment has been captured and send it to a third-party shipping company (DHL). Some of the fields I need are Name, Country, City, Address, OrderID, etc. Kindly note that I am just getting familiar with Magento and its functionalities. I am aware of events and observers but never used them for implementation before. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the event `checkout_submit_all_after`

1. create `events.xml` at following location.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\frontend\events.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
        <observer name="vendor_extension_checkout_submit_all_after" instance="Vendor\Extension\Observer\Processorder" />
    </event>
</config>
```

2. now create `Processorder.php` on following location.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\Observer\Processorder.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;


class Processorder implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{ 
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        // DO YOUr LOGIC HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know of a good way to test if the observer will actually get the order and print some output as ``` $orderId = $order->getId(); ```? If yes, where can I see the output? I would like to test the fields I can scrap before setting up and calling the API. Thank you!

Comment: UPDATE: I tried running the following line of code but the nothing is shown in the debug file: 
$order = $observer->getOrder();
        echo $orderId = $order->getId();
 $this->_logger->debug(var_export($order, true));
$this->_logger->debug(var_export($orderId, true));

Comment: Kindly check you implement the code properly.

Comment: https://snipboard.io/FuhVjO.jpg <-- Here is the set up. I still can't get it to show any results in the debug.log. Is it possible that the reason why the observer is not running are the test orders with a sandbox credit card payment? Although the orders are showing in the backend with 'Pending' status.

Comment: have you created rest of the required file of third party extension? and your extension is enable? Have you check that things with offline payment first.

Comment: Before I try to connect to the API, I need to make sure that the observer is working properly and that I can scrap the right data that I need. I am trying to print out the results after a successful order in the debug log. The offline payment goes to a sandbox, and the order is processed and redirects me to the successful checkout page. 

This event should work any time an order has been placed, which is true in this case, when I am trying to print to debug console, nothing is being shown. I also tried $orderId->debug(); and $order->debug(); Portion of debug log:https://justpaste.it/5hxye